# Laziness of infinite lists under monadic context in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

I'm currently learning haskell for the first time, and I'm having lots of trouble understanding lazy evaluation.

Main problem is that among following scenarios, some behaves lazily and some doesn't, and I can't explain why any of them do so.

Monadic iterate, or `iterateM` function I'll be using is defined as below.

```hs
iterateM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m a) -> a -> m [a]
iterateM f v = f v >>= go
  where go v' = (v' :) <$> iterateM f v'
```

- Scenario 1

  ```hs
  something :: IO [Int]
  something = return [1 ..]
  take 5 <$> something -- Fine
  ```

  Above works with any monads (At least from my experimentation).
- Scenario 2

  ```hs
  something :: Product [Int]
  something = iterateM return 5
  take 5 <$> something -- Fine
  ```

  Above works with Identity, Sum, etc.
- Scenario 3

  ```hs
  something :: IO [Int]
  something = iterateM return 5
  take 5 <$> something -- Infinite Loop !
  ```

  Above loops infinitely with List, Maybe, etc.

I did some other experiments involving `unsafePerformIO` to print when certain value is computed, and ended up suspecting that **`fmap` implementation of some functors require right hand side to be computed fully, which breaks laziness**. However then why would *Scenario 1* not loop infinitely when I clearly applies `fmap` with `take 5` ? And why would that even be a case for `IO` monad ?

So, why does above scenarios act in such way ?

-------------- Edited --------------

Thanks to all helpful answers, now I understand what is happening. My understanding is actually approached in very conceptual and mathematical way. For any future references I will write down how I understood it.

---------- My Explanation ----------

IO type is equivalent to `IO a = World -> (World, a)`. This can roughly be considered as two separate function, transformation `t :: (World -> World)`, and product `p :: (World -> a)` just combined into tuple.

Let's think about `IO` functor, or `fmap` function for `IO` type. This has type signature of `(a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b`. If you interpret this as function taking a function to be fmapped `f`, a world transformation `t`, product function `p` and returns some world transformation, and new product function, it becomes kinda easy to implement. You simply leave transformation same, and composite `f` with `p` for product.

```hs
fmap :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> World -> (World, b)
fmap f x world =
  let newT = t
      newP = f . p in
    (newT world, newP world)
  where
    t = fst . x
    p = snd . x
```

Now consider `IO` monad's `μ` transform, or `join` function. It has type signature of `IO (IO a) -> IO a`, which is equivalent to `(World -> (World, IO a)) -> (World -> (World, a))`. This looks intimidating, but if you think tuple as two separate functions, you have `t1 :: World -> World`, `p1 :: World -> IO a`, and return value of `p1` contains two functions `t2 :: World -> World`, `p2 :: World -> (World, a)`. Now it becomes obvious how `join` would be implemented for `IO` monad.

```hs
join :: IO (IO a) -> World -> (World, a)
join x world =
  let newT = t2 . t1
      newP = p2 . t1 in
    (newT world, newP world)
  where
    t1 :: World -> World
    t2 :: World -> World
    p2 :: World -> a
    t1 = fst . x
    p1 = snd . x
    t2 = fst . p1
    p2 = snd . p1
```

With `join` defined, bind function `>>=` can be defined as,

```hs
=<< :: (a -> IO b) -> IO a -> IO b
=<< = join . fmap

>>= :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
>>= = flip (=<<)
```

This means it's transformation function is composition of first argument's and return value's of second argument.

We're almost there, let's think about `η` transform, or `return` function. It's very simple,

```hs
return :: a -> World -> (World, a)
return x world =
  let newT = id
      newP = const x
    (newT world, newP world)
```

Now consult scenario 3 again.

```hs
iterateM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m a) -> a -> m [a]
iterateM f v = f v >>= go
  where go v' = (v' :) <$> iterateM f v'

something :: IO [Int]
something = iterateM return 5
take 5 <$> something
```

What would be transformation function for `something` ? Okay, since it's doing bind function, we can think it as composition of `t1` from `f v`, which is `id`, and `t2` from return value of `go`. Then what is transformation function of return value of `go` ? Well, we `fmap` something, so it will be same as right hand side... and there's the infinite loop. Essentially it is infinite composition of `id`s.

Note that the product function also is infinite compositions of `(5 :)` and `id`. It won't be a problem to be infinitely composed towards left side, such as `... . (5 :) . (5 :)`, but the product is also infinitely composed towards right side with `id`s.

I think this is what Willem meant by,

> `IO` is a monad that also is exactly defined to run things in a specific order ...

that functions are composed in specific order to ensure IO are performed in specific order. And if you iterate infinitely, it will get composed infinitely.

Additionally, Scenario 3 not working with `List` or `Maybe` is rather simple. `join` function for `Maybe` monad requires knowing if right hand side is `Just` or `Nothing`. It's actually even documented as laziness breakers in [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maintaining_laziness) because of such property. `List` monad is just me being stupid. `List` `fmap` requires to know nth element of right hand side in order to deduce the return value's nth element. And looking closely to the code, it can't deduce any element.

Scenario 1 would of course work because `IO` monad itself is not breaking laziness of inner value magically, but compositing product and transformation function does.

Of course above code is not how actual haskell's `IO` is implemented because, you can't really capture `World` and apply operations in real world. But conceptually it explains.

Comment: `iterateM` will require performing all the operations, since that is exactly what `IO` here is supposed to do: enforce the order between computations. So it will require doing all `return`s.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but thanks for the answer! After thinking `IO` monad as World transformer function, and considering how `fmap` would need to compute all right hand sides, I figured out why all above would happen.

Comment: `fmap` does not *always* have to do that. For example for your `Product`, it doesn't: the right hand side is always a `Product`, so it will essentially store an expression in a `Product` that pretends `v` to the thing that still needs to be evaluated at the right hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the `>>=`, depending on what it does. For `Product`, the `Monad` instance is implemented as:

```
instance Monad Product where
    m >>= k  = k (getProduct m)
```

thus

```
iterateM f v = go (getProduct (Product v))
  where go v' = (v' :) <$> iterateM f v'
```

We can remote the `Product` and `getProduct` functions since these just wrap and unwrap it from the data constructor.

```
iterateM f v = go v
  where go v' = (v' :) <$> iterateM f v'
```

or thus:

```
iterateM f v = go
  where go = (v' :) <$> go
```

it thus will prepend a `v'` to the list wrapped in the `go`. For a `Product` it does not matter what the right hand side is: we know it can only be a product, and we don't need to evaluate the value wrapped in the `Product` either, since we just leave the function call (here `(v' :)`) to a value that might still need to be evaluated.

This thus means that for a `Product` with an undefined value wrapped in it, or even an `undefined` product, we get:

```
(take 1 . (0:) <$> (undefined :: Product [Int]))
Product {getProduct = [0]}
```

Now for `IO` that is not the case, `IO` is a monad that also is exactly defined to run things in a specific order: it thus prevents writing a second byte to a file before the first one, because the lazy evaluation somehow evaluated the second one first: it's main function is to guarantee that the order of evaluation, for IO operations only though, remains intact.

But for `IO` this, thus means that if you have `f v >>= go`, it will thus first run `f v` and *then* `go`, and since `go` eventually is another `f v >>= go`, you thus keep producing operations to perform before the computation ends, and thus it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

To understand when a recursive function is defined, you replace all of its recursive calls with `undefined` and see whether the result is `undefined` (or infinite loop or another error) (in which case the recursive function is `undefined`), or some possibly partial value (in which case the recursive function is at least as defined as that).

`iterate f v` makes a recursive call to `iterate f v'` under a `<$>` (and `>>=`). Whether this is defined thus depends on the strictness (laziness) of `<$>` (and `>>=`), that is to say, whether the following equation holds:

```
f <$> undefined = undefined
```

For `Identity` (which is the same as `Sum` and `Product`), `<$>` is nonstrict if the function argument is nonstrict. (The `Identity` constructor is a newtype constructor, which does not exist at runtime and thus does not affect strictness.)

```
f <$> Identity x = Identity (f x)
```

Let us evaluate `iterate return 5`. The first two steps below do not depend on the monad (the first step is simply unfolding the definition, the second step is a monad law):

```
iterate return 5
  = return 5 >>= \v -> ((v :) <$> iterate return v)
  = (5 :) <$> iterate return 5
```

To tell whether that's defined, we replace the recursive call to `iterate` on the right hand side with `undefined`.

```
(5 :) <$> undefined
```

For `Identity`, which is a newtype, `undefined = Identity undefined` (the `Identity` pattern does not force its contents.)

```
(5 :) <$> undefined = (5 :) <$> Identity undefined = Identity (5 : undefined)
```

Hence `iterate return 5` is at least equal to `Identity (5 : undefined)`. Further approximations can be obtained by replacing `iterate return 5` by that partial result instead of `undefined`, and repeating.

In contrast, `IO` has a strict `<$>`: `undefined :: IO a` is a crashing program, and applying `<$>` just produces another crashing program.

```
iterate return 5 = (5 :) <$> iterate return 5
```

Replace the recursive call to `iterate` with `undefined`

```
((5 :) <$> undefined) = undefined
```

because `<$>` is strict for `IO`. Thus `iterate return 5 :: IO [Int]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! This also explains really well about laziness in general, but I accepted Willem's answer because he's quick comment helped me get motivations to investigate on difference between those monads.